# MVC3, RavenDB, AutoMapper, IoC/DI and Geese - where should I use my associated repositories?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, ravendb

I'm very new to RavenDB and MVC3, in particular the usage (not concept) of IoC.  So just to warn you that this will sound like a very beginner question.

In summary:
I have a domain model, let's say it's

```
public class Goose
```

Within this class I might have a more complex object as a property

```
    public Beak beak { get; set; }
```

In RavenDB we are rightly encouraged to [JsonIgnore] this property or not have it at all and instead have a reference identifier, like

```
    public String beakId { get; set; }
```

Somwhere along the way in my MVC3 application I will want to view the Goose and I might want to display to the user, something about the Goose and it's Beak (should that be Bill?).  So yeah I need a view model right?

```
public class GooseModel
{
    public String BeakColour { get; set; }
    public String BeakLength { get; set; }
    ...etc
}
```

Right, so assuming I have some GooseRepository and some BeakRepository here's the simple question....

I'm in the GooseController class and I'm loading a Goose to view.  At what point do I use the BeakRepository and who should know about it?  The GooseController knows about the GooseRepository and is loading the Goose by id.  At this point we could have some property inside the Goose class which represents the whole Beak, but I don't really want to inject the BeakRepository into the GooseRepository do I?  Ok, so perhaps when I create the GooseModel from the Goose I've found I could get the GooseModel properties for the BeakColour and BeakLength, how? Well I like AutoMapper, so perhapds my Map For the GooseModel from Goose is using the BeakRepository to find the Beak and then extract the two Beak properties to populate the GooseModel fields.. this too seems wrong... so what's left?  The GooseController.. should the Goose controller know about the BeakRespository and then find and set the BeakColour and BeakLength!? that certainly seems completely wrong too..

So where does it get done? the Controller, the domain object, the mapper or somewhere else?  Perhaps I should have a partial view of Type Beak which is used within the Goose view?..

Comment: I'd actually argue that in Raven you probably want the Beak to be a complex object/property of the goose rather than a separate document. Generally the examples about for this kind of things are very, very poor when it comes to documentdbs.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to consolidate this kind of logic into a service/business layer (`GooseService`) that i then inject into the controller.  your service layer might take a `GooseRepository` and a `BeakRepository`, and return a resolved object that has mapped the `GooseViewModel` together.

Comment: Ah, so the GooseService would bear the responsibility of generating/mapping the GooseModel?  I guess there would be some kind of resolver in play here that is responsible for providing the GooseService?

Comment: correct.  depending on your preference, you'd just pick an ioc container and wire it up.  you'd need to create a custom DependencyResolver for your chosen ioc container, as that's how your controllers would be built.  I default to structuremap, but ninject is good, and i've heard good things about newer versions of unity.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking into these and started with StructureMap, but I must say I'm struggling to find a simple IoC with MVC3 example which uses StructureMap and clearly defines where to put what.  I can see how the code would execute and run a UT, but it's not clear how to wire it up in the asax app startup

Comment: here's a start to finish structuremap mvc3.  its a decent implementation.  http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/how-do-i-use-structuremap-with-asp-net-mvc-3/

Answer (score 1):

Uhm,... reading your question I strongly suggest you forget about the Service-Layer and the Repository-Layer. If you don't have really good reasons to keep them (testing is not one of them since RavenDB has an EmbeddableDocumentStore, which is fast and easy) pull them in order to take advantage of some very nice features of RavenDB.

I've actually written a post about why I think you should generally avoid these layers:
http://daniellang.net/keep-your-code-simple/ It is about NHibernate, but concepts apply here as well.

Whether you should denormalize the BeakColor and BeakLength property into your Goose-document depends on your applications need. If you feel comfortable with the term "aggregate root", then the rule of thumb is that these generally are your documents. If you're not sure whether denormalization should be applied, avoid it, and use `.Include(goose => goose.Beak)` instead when loading your Goose.

Please let me know if that makes sense to you.

Comment: There's never a true "right" way of doing things in programming and I'm getting fairly frustrated with the number of different approaches to MVC3.  Saying that, your suggestion of doing away with the repository layer is interesting.  I am currently trying to learn best practise so the "need" is not really a factor.  I suppose I could still use the repository and ask it to include the Beak when retrieving from Raven and then populate a non-serialized object property from the beakId.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Ha! I've read your article, very very good point.  My career started in the the classic ASP inline SQL using ADO days and I gotta say I could get stuff done very quickly.  Of course I grew out of it and used a lot of VB/C++ COM stuff and later .Net.  But I do get a sinking feeling every time I start with anything recent.  Some great ideas out there, but they don't all have to be used at once..

Comment: Glad to hear you like the idea. As for populating the Goose object, I'm not sure I understand your question. It might help you to look at the RaccoonBlog sample (https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog). If not you can drop me an email too.